# How can I find numbers for $x$ so that $x + \frac{1}{10}x = n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any way to find the first few $x$ so that

$$x + \frac{1}{10}x = n \text{ with } x\in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

holds?

Maybe this is also the wrong approach; I want to get only the integral numbers for which above condition holds.

Comment: Algebra perhaps?

Comment: Consider $x(1+\frac{1}{10})=n$

Comment: you are right, I mixed up the set of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x+\frac{x}{10}=\frac{11}{10}x=n$$
For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we need $10\mid11x$. Now $\gcd(10,11)=1$ and thus this is equivalent to $10\mid x$. So the equation is fulfilled for any $x$ that is a multiple of $10$, namely $x=10\cdot k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

EDIT: There solution above does not produce all solutions since I falsely assumed $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks to @Stu for pointing this out. All solutions are then given by
$$\frac{11}{10}x=n\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{10}{11}n\qquad,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: $x=\dfrac{10n}{11}$ also for instance $x=\dfrac{10}{11}$ with $n=1$

Comment: so $S=\bigg\{\dfrac{10n}{11}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\bigg\}$

Comment: Sorry, that mistake was careless of me. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

$x + \frac{1}{10} x = \frac{11}{10} x$
Basic algebra right?

Comment: you are right, I made an error with the set of numbers. Please see the edit I just made